# How to Optimize complex query with 17 join tables and limiting data per join using LIMIT syntx

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-12

I have the following example of complex queries that get generated in our system. In this example, we're turning data that is joined to 17 other tables. For each of the join tables, I am using the syntax LIMIT keyword to limit returned number of items per join table. The goal was to retrieve a max of 50 items per join table. For queries with far fewer joins (7-10), this seems to work ok.

However, using the limit of 50 in this query, I get the error: Error: temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit (1025563kB).

If I change the limit from 50 to 5, the query runs in 36s seconds. If I change the limit from 50 to 3, it runs in 3 seconds. If I change it to 2, it runs in 260ms

My question is, is there a more efficient way to run a complex query like this that could return that 50 items per join? Or is that too much for single query for postgres to process?

It's curious it drops to 260ms with reducing the # of returned sub items from 5 to 2.

```
SELECT Count (*),
       array_to_json((Array_agg(t))[0:500]) AS array
FROM   (
                 SELECT    tbl_338.id,
                           custom.fullname AS "CustomID",
                           tbl_338.field_7,
                           tbl_338.field_6,
                           tbl_338.field_5,
                           tbl_338.field_1,
                           tbl_338.field_2,
                           tbl_338.field_18,
                           tbl_338.field_17,
                           tbl_338.field_3,
                           tbl_338.field_32,
                           tbl_338.addedon,
                           tbl_338.updatedon,
                           tbl_338.field_16,
                           tbl_338.id,
                           tbl_338.addedby,
                           tbl_338.updatedby ,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('id',tbl_340_field_15.id,'data',tbl_340_field_15.fullname))                                                                 AS field_15,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('id',tbl_408_field_30.id,'data',tbl_408_field_30.fullname))                                                                 AS field_30,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('id',tbl_342_field_19.id,'data',tbl_342_field_19.fullname))                                                                 AS field_19 ,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_34.optionid,'data',field_34.OPTION,'attributes',field_34.attributes))                                      AS field_34,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_23.optionid,'data',field_23.OPTION,'attributes',field_23.attributes))                                      AS field_23,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_24.optionid,'data',field_24.OPTION,'attributes',field_24.attributes))                                      AS field_24,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_22.optionid,'data',field_22.OPTION,'attributes',field_22.attributes))                                      AS field_22,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_33.optionid,'data',field_33.OPTION,'attributes',field_33.attributes))                                      AS field_33,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_37.optionid,'data',field_37.OPTION,'attributes',field_37.attributes))                                      AS field_37,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_36.optionid,'data',field_36.OPTION,'attributes',field_36.attributes))                                      AS field_36,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_21.optionid,'data',field_21.OPTION,'attributes',field_21.attributes))                                      AS field_21,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_38.optionid,'data',field_38.OPTION,'attributes',field_38.attributes))                                      AS field_38,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_14.optionid,'data',field_14.OPTION,'attributes',field_14.attributes))                                      AS field_14,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_31.optionid,'data',field_31.OPTION,'attributes',field_31.attributes))                                      AS field_31,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('optionid',field_8.optionid,'data',field_8.OPTION,'attributes',field_8.attributes))                                         AS field_8 ,
                           jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('messageid',msg.messageid,'message',msg.message,'schedule',msg.schedule,'tablerowid',msg.tablerowid,'addedon',msg.addedon)) AS field_4
                 FROM      schema_131.tbl_338 tbl_338
                 LEFT JOIN schema_131.tbl_338_customid custom
                 ON        custom.id=tbl_338.id
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_15.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_to_tbl_340_field_15 field_15
                                           WHERE           field_15.tbl_338_field_15_id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_15
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT tbl_340_field_15.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_340_customid tbl_340_field_15
                                           WHERE           tbl_340_field_15.id = field_15.tbl_340_field_5_id limit 50 ) tbl_340_field_15
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_30.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_408_to_tbl_338_field_4 field_30
                                           WHERE           field_30.tbl_338_field_30_id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_30
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT tbl_408_field_30.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_408_customid tbl_408_field_30
                                           WHERE           tbl_408_field_30.id = field_30.tbl_408_field_4_id limit 50 ) tbl_408_field_30
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_19.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_to_tbl_342_field_19 field_19
                                           WHERE           field_19.tbl_338_field_19_id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_19
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT tbl_342_field_19.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_342_customid tbl_342_field_19
                                           WHERE           tbl_342_field_19.id = field_19.tbl_342_field_5_id limit 50 ) tbl_342_field_19
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_34_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_34_join field_34_join
                                           WHERE           field_34_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_34_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_34.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_34 field_34
                                           WHERE           field_34.optionid = field_34_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_34.rank limit 5 ) field_34
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_23_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_23_join field_23_join
                                           WHERE           field_23_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_23_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_23.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_23 field_23
                                           WHERE           field_23.optionid = field_23_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_23.rank limit 5 ) field_23
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_24_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_24_join field_24_join
                                           WHERE           field_24_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_24_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_24.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_24 field_24
                                           WHERE           field_24.optionid = field_24_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_24.rank limit 5 ) field_24
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_22_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_22_join field_22_join
                                           WHERE           field_22_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_22_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_22.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_22 field_22
                                           WHERE           field_22.optionid = field_22_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_22.rank limit 5 ) field_22
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_33_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_33_join field_33_join
                                           WHERE           field_33_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_33_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_33.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_33 field_33
                                           WHERE           field_33.optionid = field_33_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_33.rank limit 5 ) field_33
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_37_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_37_join field_37_join
                                           WHERE           field_37_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_37_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_37.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_37 field_37
                                           WHERE           field_37.optionid = field_37_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_37.rank limit 5 ) field_37
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_36_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_36_join field_36_join
                                           WHERE           field_36_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_36_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_36.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_36 field_36
                                           WHERE           field_36.optionid = field_36_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_36.rank limit 5 ) field_36
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_21_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_21_join field_21_join
                                           WHERE           field_21_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_21_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_21.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_21 field_21
                                           WHERE           field_21.optionid = field_21_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_21.rank limit 5 ) field_21
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_38_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_38_join field_38_join
                                           WHERE           field_38_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_38_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_38.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_38 field_38
                                           WHERE           field_38.optionid = field_38_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_38.rank limit 5 ) field_38
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_14_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_14_join field_14_join
                                           WHERE           field_14_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_14_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_14.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_14 field_14
                                           WHERE           field_14.optionid = field_14_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_14.rank limit 5 ) field_14
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_31_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_31_join field_31_join
                                           WHERE           field_31_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_31_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_31.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_31 field_31
                                           WHERE           field_31.optionid = field_31_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_31.rank limit 5 ) field_31
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_8_join.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_8_join field_8_join
                                           WHERE           field_8_join.id=tbl_338.id limit 50) field_8_join
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT field_8.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.tbl_338_field_8 field_8
                                           WHERE           field_8.optionid = field_8_join.optionid
                                           ORDER BY        field_8.rank limit 5 ) field_8
                 ON        true
                 LEFT JOIN lateral
                           (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT msg.*
                                           FROM            schema_131.messages msg
                                           WHERE           msg.graceblockssms=tbl_338.smsnumber
                                           AND             msg.recipientsms=tbl_338.field_3
                                           ORDER BY        msg.addedon DESC limit 1) msg
                 ON        true
                 GROUP BY  tbl_338.id,
                           custom.fullname,
                           tbl_338.field_7,
                           tbl_338.field_6,
                           tbl_338.field_5,
                           tbl_338.field_1,
                           tbl_338.field_2,
                           tbl_338.field_18,
                           tbl_338.field_17,
                           tbl_338.field_3,
                           tbl_338.field_32,
                           tbl_338.addedon,
                           tbl_338.updatedon,
                           tbl_338.field_16,
                           tbl_338.id,
                           tbl_338.addedby,
                           tbl_338.updatedby
                 ORDER BY  tbl_338.id ASC ) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **PostGreSQL is not designed for complex queries**... You should use another RDBMS that support such complexity.

1. PostGreSQL limits the optimization of join to 12 by a parameter
   call "*geqo_threshold*" (default value is 12)
2. In PG, the time to find an optimized execution plan is a factorial of JOIN, due to the algorithm used in the optimizer...
3. If you set *geqo_threshold* to an upper value, the time taken to compute an
   optimized plan, will increase too much and can be superior to the
   execution of the query with a trivial execution plan.
4. If you leave the actuel value of *geqo_threshold*, the excution plan will
   probably be computed in less time, but will offer a worst execution
   plan..

So you have a dilemma:

- do you want a worst execution plan
- do you want a good execution plan, that will tak too much time to compute

The discussion about the use of geqo by the PG staff, reveal a dead end...
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/geqo-pg-intro.html#GEQO-FUTURE

**So, what to do ?**

**FIRST**: try to increase the geqo_threshold and make some tests. But use a real world amount of data you shoukld have in 3 to 5 years to To avoid compromising your project.

**SECOND**: if your results, from FIRST part, concludes that this is an inacceptable situation... transfer your database to a RDBMS that do not have problems with such a situation. Microsoft SQL Server is actually the best choice for this (the best optimizer over Oracle at less cost) and SQL Server is available on Linux.

To have a look of the limitations of PostGreSQL and the bad performances, just read my papers :
http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/
http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/
http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-part-1-dba-queries-performances/